# Were the Augments from the show "Enterprise" the same genetically enhanced people that were in "The original Star Trek series?"

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tos, star-trek-enterprise

In ENT: "Augments" there are a group of 19 genetically enhanced human embryos that Dr. Arik Soong stole out of a secret medical facility and raised as his children. Later in the episode Dr. Arik Soong goes back to that medical facility, takes the rest of the 1800 embryos and was going to bring them to life (ie continue their development).

ENT: "Cold Station 12":

> ARCHER: It's the embryos from the Eugenics Wars that Soong's after.
>
> TUCKER: I thought Soong stole the embryos.
>
> ARCHER: He took nineteen, but there are **over eighteen hundred more.**
>
> TUCKER: That's why he took the incubators with him.
>
> T'POL: Why weren't these embryos destroyed after the war?

Were the Augments and Embryos in ST:ENT "Augments" from the same genetically engineered group that Khan Noonien Singh and his companions on The SS Botany Bay were from in TOS: "Space Seed?"

If they are a different group why were they created?

Comment: fixed @cde thx, late here and those xanax kicked in, ha ha

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Yes

These were the same group of Augments.  The [Memory Alpha page on Augments](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Augment) explains the following:

> The Augments [from the 1950s - seen in *Space Seed*] were finally overthrown in 1996; the last to be deposed
>   was Khan Noonien Singh. After the end of the war some eighty Augments
>   were unaccounted for, including Khan. (Star Trek II: The Wrath of
>   Khan) *Earth authorities collected the remaining Augment embryos and
>   placed them into storage; by the 2130s **they were stored on the Earth
>   Starfleet facility Cold Station 12***. (ENT: "Cold Station 12")

(emphasis mine)

Comment: I thought it was station 31 and it was over 1800 embryos that Soong grabbed.

Comment: @JMFB the episode is called 'Cold Station 12' and I haven't actually mentioned how many Augments Soong took - the 80 Augments were the ones that fled Earth

Comment: So 80 fled on ss bottany bay then?

Comment: @JMFB presumably; I got the feeling there was more than that, or perhaps another ship but I can't seem to find anymore

Comment: Thanks, good answer. I wonder if Khan after he was woken by Kirk knew about the events in ENT: Cold Station 12 and Arik Soong.

Comment: @JMFB probably not, considering that he had been asleep for that period.  I guess when he was reading through the *Enterprise* computer library he may have come across it.  Interesting idea!

Comment: you'd think that during the wrath of khan when he first gets the ship his priority would have been to get the embryos instead of Kirk, then he'd have an army instead of just a few men.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25900/discussion-between-jmfb-and-n-soong).